# Are there other advantages to using turf over grass seed besides getting instant results? 

Tags: landscaping, grass, planting, turf

As I mentioned in a previous post, I'm planning to eventually have a lawn in our front yard (right now, it's bare due to septic work).  I'm confused on if there are clear advantages to using turf vs just planting the seed.

As far as I can tell, the only major difference is time.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: should be moved to the gardening stack

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've looked at this in the past.  These two links are pretty general, but each has an interesting tidbit.

[Link 1](http://www.allaboutlawns.com/lawn-maintenance-care/planting-and-repair/to-seed-or-sod.php) "If your yard has especially shady spots, you might be better off seeding those areas, since most sod is made up of sun-thirsty grass varieties."

[Link 2](http://www.uvm.edu/pss/ppp/articles/seedsod.html) "A prime disadvantage of sod is the limited number of grass species included in sod mixes."

Other than that, sod is a clear winner if you have more money than time.  I've done both, killed both, and revived both...lets just say I'm eyeing my neighbor's lovely rock garden with a bit of envy.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried sods, divets and seeding using kikuyu (fast growing, sun loving and hardy). My experiences have been the following:

- Sods established quickly with lots of watering and sun but were a little disappointing in shaded areas. However, you can walk on them after a short period without causing much damage.
- Divets grew quickly but toke a long time to spread. I had a grid like pattern for a while. Steer away from divets for large areas but they're still good for fixing patches.
- Seeds germinated after 2 weeks but toke a few months to establish. The cover or pathchiness was a function of how much seed I put down. Also the young grass is less hardy so you need to keep your dogs/kids/relatives off until it is established.

I personally got a lot of satisfaction out of seeding but its not suitable for quick fixes. I'd recommend sods.

Answer (score 0):

Turf and grass seed both have some advantages and disadvantages in many ways i.e., it depends upon the situation while choosing the right decision for your lawn.

Let's see some of the advantages of using turf over grass as listed below:

1. It's an instant lawn available to you within a month
2. During heavy rain it doesn't wash up the slopes like grass seed does
3. Requires less water